# How to fix "future returned by is not `Send`" when using Mutex in axum?

Tags: rust, async-await, mutex, rust-axum

I wanted to implement an authorization code flow in axum with PKCE. Therefore I have to hand over the generated PKCE code verifier to the callback route in order to exchange the code for a token, so that I can proceed logging my user in with a session and such.

Right now I mainly use a hammer, just to describe why the solution might look like it does:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct AppState {
    db: PgPool,
    oauth_client: BasicClient,
    verifiers: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, String>>>,
}

#[debug_handler]
async fn callback(
    State(state): State<AppState>,
    Query(auth_request): Query<AuthRequest>,
) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, impl IntoResponse> {
    let auth_request = auth_request;

    let verifiers = state.verifiers.lock().unwrap();
    let pkce_verifier = verifiers.get(&auth_request.state).unwrap().into();
    let pkce_verifier = PkceCodeVerifier::new(pkce_verifier);

    let _token_result = match state
        .oauth_client
        .exchange_code(AuthorizationCode::new(auth_request.code))
        .set_pkce_verifier(pkce_verifier)
        .request_async(async_http_client)
        .await
    {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(e) => {
            error!("could not exchange code: {e}");
            return Err((StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.to_string()));
        }
    };

    Ok(Redirect::temporary("/"))
}
```

the error is as follows:

```
  --> src/main.rs:134:10
    |
125 |     let verifiers = state.verifiers.lock().unwrap();
    |         --------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>>` which is not `Send`
134 |         .await
    |          ^^^^^ await occurs here, with `verifiers` maybe used later
```

I understand that the lock on the mutex is hold too long. I've tried to understand lots of similar problems, but I am not able to understand this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust's `std::sync::Mutex` cannot be held across an `await` point, which is why you're seeing the `type is not Send` compile error. You have two options:

1. Drop the lock before you reach an `await` point. You only use `verifiers` to get `pkce_verifier`, so you could just inline it:

   ```rust
   let pkce_verifier = state
       .verifiers
       .lock()
       .unwrap()
       .get(&auth_request.state)
       .unwrap()
       .into();
   ```

   That is somewhat ugly, so you could also just manually call `drop()` on the lock:

   ```rust
   let verifiers = state.verifiers.lock().unwrap();
   let pkce_verifier = verifiers.get(&auth_request.state).unwrap().into();
   drop(verifiers);
   ```

   Alternatively, you could create and use the lock within an inner block scope, which will automatically drop the lock when the block exits scope:

   ```rust
   let pkce_verifier = {
       let verifiers = state.verifiers.lock().unwrap();
       verifiers.get(&auth_request.state).unwrap().into()
   };
   ```
2. You could use an async-aware lock, like `futures::lock::Mutex`. If you think you will need to use a mutex across an `await` point in the future, you could just switch to an async-aware mutex. Otherwise, the standard library mutex will work as long as the lock isn't held across an `await` point.

---

As a side note, it's bad practice to call `.unwrap()` on objects unless you're sure the field exists. Especially in the case of a `HashMap`, you should use pattern matching or built-in `Option`-to-`Result` functions Rust provides like `ok_or()`.

Comment: thank you @nicholas-crothers for the explanation. To be honest I tried a manual drop before, but probably on the wrong place. The block expression makes total sense! Yes true I need to get better in handling the types correctly.